# Expression should return the same type 'integer' as previous expressions (iif) in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have 2 datetime columns in my dataset. Firstly, I am checking if EndTime is lesser than StartTime before getting the difference in minutes. My expression is like so:

```
iif(EndTime <= StartTime, 0, ((EndTime  - StartTime) / 6000))
```

I was expecting to return minutes in an integer where values are equal to or greater than 0

I am not sure what is wrong with my expression.
I anticipate your feedback.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to rework my expression and get it to return the expected result. Below is the expression that worked for me:

```
 toInteger(toString(iif(EndTime <= StartTime, 0, toInteger(toString(minus({EndTime}, {StartTime})))/ 60000)))
```